I would like to use ShareDeviceRequest for the first commissioning, is this a valid use case?
My app is a companion app for a matter device, however the app itself is NOT a commissioner app.
The app will set the device in commissioning mode and then, for a better user experience, my app should guide the user to commission their device into their favorite controller app. The reason to do this are:

The half sheet notification that pops up automatically isn't extremely reliable because it doesn't always come up immediately and it currently seems to work only on Pixel phones. Samsung doesn't have it at all apparently. When the half sheet isn't present, the user has to figure out that they have to open their favorite commissioner app and do all the work manually without any guidance.
I can avoid the user the hassle to use QR code or manual PIN, the proof of ownership is provided by the app having the device installed in the user account itself.
Commissioning Apps other than Google Home have the same relevance, and the user doesn't have to necessarily go through Google Home, or it's not always the default choice.

The best way of doing so seems to be the half bottom sheet that is usually used for sharing a device once it's been already commissioned once, using the CommissioningClient.shareDevice() method - see documentation.

I used the code as per code lab directions - see codelab - and it seems to work correctly, I can properly commission my device into Google Home, even without commissioning it in the local Android fabric first. So that is great.
My main concern is: the CommissioningClient.shareDevice() is meant to share an already commissioned device to another fabric, but can it be used for the very first commissioning? It works now, but will it stop working at some point because it's not an expected use case?
Does anyone have any idea on this topic?
